# how to pass max_streak_length from command line

Tags: c++, mpi, command-line-arguments

I'm using MPI to create C++ console app my problem is I have max_streak_length var  is hard code I need to pass it from command line. my command line `mpiexec -n 3 main.exe 6` where 6 is my max_streak_length.can someone help me?

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    //init size of max win streak
    int max_streak_length  = 6;


    //init MPI 
    if(MPI_Init(&argc,&argv) == MPI_SUCCESS)
    {
        //init number of process and rank
        int numProc , rank;

        MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&numProc);
        MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&rank);


        //call the process master 
        if(rank == 0)
            procMaster(numProc,max_streak_length);
        //call the process slaves
        else
            procSlave(numProc,rank,max_streak_length);

        MPI_Finalize();
    }



    //playGame(15);

    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple answer is

```
int max_streak_length = atoi(argv[1]);
```

Note that with anything passed from the command line you really should add some error checking, you should check that the argument is actually there (i.e. that argc > 1) and that the value entered really is an integer, and that it's value is in the range you expect etc. etc.